# My SimpleDateFormat doesn't work as expected! (About Locale)

Tags: java, android, locale, simpledateformat

Well, I am trying to print the toast message on my phone, Android.
But the matter is that locale doesn't work. I tried to write the codes, "Locale.KOREAN", in the second parameter of SimpleDateFormat as you can see. It doesn't work. Even though I live in Seoul, South Korea which is GMT +09:00, SimpleDateFormat's default Timezone doens't work properly. Is there any possible solution? (How to fix my default timezone or something else)

```
package org.androidtown.customerinformation;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Today implements Parcelable {

    Date now = new Date();

    SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd a hh:mm:ss z", Locale.KOREAN);

    String Time = currentTime.format(now);

    public Today() {

    }

    public Today(Parcel src) {

        Time = src.readString();
    }

    public String getCurrentTime() {
        return Time;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {

        public Today createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Today(in);
        }

        public Today[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Today[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(Time);
    }
}
```

When I make a Toast message, just like

```
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + today.getCurrentTime(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It saids GMT 00:00 of course, the time is wrong too.

Comment: Do you really need a whole class just to get the timestamp string for right now?

Comment: Oh, and I am using Android Studio 2.2.2 and making this project with Gradle 2.14.2 and JDK 1.8.0_91 - b15 (Java TM SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91 -b15))

Comment: Why do you think that `SimpleDateFormat` cares about the time zone of your passed `Locale`? The JavaDoc also doesn't assert that.

Comment: @cricket_007 There is more factors and methods for another works but, I dropped it because of asking.

Comment: @Tom I saw some examples about this. And if there is no reference about timezone, it is going to be default which is my current timezone isn't it?

Comment: It uses the timezone where you currently are, not necessarily related to the passed `Locale`. You can check `currentTime.getCalendar().getTimeZone()` to see which timezone it uses.